# I'am looking for a formula by which I can join two cells(One cell contains TEXT, Other cell contains HYPERLINK URL)into single HYPERLINKED cell

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 columns, the cells of the first column contain TEXT while cells of the second column Contain HYPERLINKS. I want o combine both the cells into third column, such that it overall becomes a hyperlink.

Example- [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RcDp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=HYPERLINK(B1,A1&" "&B1)` is the answer to your question if the data is in A1 and B1.
However I recommend using `=HYPERLINK(B1,A1)`
It then shows the short description, but links to the long link.